# Symfony, Wrap Form Collection in Tag

Tags: php, symfony, twig, themes

I'm writing a plugin for Silex-based web application.

I'm trying to embed a form collection inside an existing form. I can include the new form easily enough, but I need to be able to modify the output, and I'm simply confused by the documentation.

**Please Note:**

1. The system uses Symfony 2.7
2. Because this is a plugin, the **only** things I can change are my form theme and the form builder used to add my fields.

**What I'm trying to do:**

Convert the embedded form to a Table. So, my first step was to try to wrap the entire nested form inside a `<table>` element.

**What I expected**

```
<table>
  <!-- Existing Embedded Form -->
</table>
```

**What I did**

```
{% block _formname_embeddedformname_row %}
<table>
  {{ form_row(form) }}
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

**What I actually get**

```
<!-- Existing Embedded Form -->
<table></table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the DOM was just coping with an incomplete `table`.

Once I implemented the correct child fragments in the form theme (including `tbody`, `tr`, and `td`), the table rendered as I expected.